# Webpack-dev-server's proxy bypass doesn't work with Angular2 routing

Tags: angular, proxy, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm implementing login for our Angular2 application.  When the Login button is clicked, an HTTP request to "/doLogin" is issued.  The Webpack-dev-server is configured to proxy that URL segment (together with a couple of others) to the backend server:

```
  proxy: [{
    context: ['/doLogin', ...],
    target: 'http://mybackendserver.com',
    secure: false
  }]
```

On successful authentication the backend server redirects the response to '/dashboard'.  (Note that we're using the PathLocationStrategy, no hashes.) But in some situations, based on a command-line argument, I want to bypass auth and go directly to the Dashboard when the Login button is clicked.

According to the Webpack-dev-server documentation: "The proxy can be optionally bypassed based on the return from a function. The function can inspect the HTTP request, response, and any given proxy options. It must return either false or a URL path that will be served instead of continuing to proxy the request." So I added such a bypass option for login:

```
  proxy: [{
    context: ['/doLogin', ...],
    target: 'http://mybackendserver.com',
    secure: false,
    bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
      if (req.url == '/doLogin' && SKIP_LOGIN) {
        return '/dashboard';
      }
    }
  }]
```

However, the dashboard is never loaded.  The page is reloaded with the default fallback route (which is the login page again).  I tried debugging into the Angular routing code, and I'm pretty sure '/dashboard' never shows up there.

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the proxy implementation?

We're currently using webpack v. 2.1.0-beta.22, webpack-dev-server v. 2.1.0-beta.2 and webpack-dev-middleware v. 1.6.1, although I tried with various combinations of more recent versions, including webpack-dev-server 2.2.0-rc.0, but they all behave the same way with regard to proxy bypass.

Comment: Do you have a guard protecting access to `/dashboard` in your application? That is something I would expect to see in a serious application.

Comment: Oh, yes, definitely, but I want to disable login for automated GUI testing.  So instead of the /dashboard I'd probably put in a special route, just for this purpose.